# Error while running VS Webtest

Tags: visual-studio, webtest, argumentnullexception

While running a simple visual studio webtest (ensure that my SERVER responds appropriately to a GET request), I get an appropriate response (i.e. the value for the key I'm passing as a parameter). However, the test fails with the following error:
"Request failed: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: uriString"
and the only available stacktrace reading:
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: uriString
   at System.Uri..ctor(String uriString, UriKind uriKind)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.WebStress.WebTestInstrumentedTransaction.ProcessCompletedRequest(Boolean completedSynchronously)"

I don't use a uriString variable anywhere in my code.

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, and it wasn't an issue with the test. My setup was responding with a 302, which needs a redirection header that was not being populated (I intended to use a 200, but confused HTTPStatusCode Found with OK), which caused the above